# How to plot residual distance from regression line using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, panel-data

I have a panel dataset which I have fit a fixed effects model to using `plm()`:

```
library(plm)
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89))

ID, year, progenyMean, damMean
1, 1, 70, 69
1, 2, 68, 69
1, 3, 72, 72
1, 4, 69, 68
2, 1, 76, 75
2, 2, 73, 80
3, 1, 72, 74
3, 2, 75, 67
3, 3, 71, 69

# Fixed Effects Model in plm
fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))
```

I have plotted progenyMean vs damMean with the fixed effects regression line in blue:

[image]

The fixed effects regression line is of the form `y=71.09+4.64564x`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=damMean, y=progenyMean)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_abline(slope=4.64564, intercept=71.09)
```

I want to plot the residual the distance of each data point from the regression line, similar to this plot here:

[image]

Is this possible to do using `ggplot()` in R?

Comment: Stack's tag-recommendation engine is imperfect, please double-check the recommended tags before saving the question. In this case, [tag:data.table] and likely [tag:panel-data] are not applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is this possible via `ggplot2`. One option would be to add the fitted values as a new column to your data frame and draw the deviations from the data points via a `geom_segment` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

intercept <- 71.09
slope <- 4.64564
data$fitted <- intercept + slope * data$damMean

ggplot(data, aes(x = damMean, y = progenyMean)) +
  geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = intercept, color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = damMean, yend = fitted, color = "resid")) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(resid = "darkred"), labels = c(resid = "residuals"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=damMean, y=progenyMean)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "lightgrey")+
    geom_segment(aes(xend = damMean, yend = predicted)) + # connect data and predicted
    geom_point(aes(alpha = abs(residuals))) +
    guides(alpha = FALSE) +
    geom_point(aes(y=predicted), shape=3, color="red") + # the predicted points
    theme_bw()
```

[image]